# When I free up memory by deleting a temporary node, I get a read access violation. But only when I return a false statement

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

I made a class that implements a doubly linked list and overloaded a comparison 
operator. I made a temp node to cycle through the link list and delete it when I am done. I get a read access violation when ever I return a false statement.
I have been stuck on it for a couple hours. Any help will be great.

```
bool operator== (const dlist& a, const dlist& b)
{
    if (a.size() != b.size())
        return false;

    bool equal = true;
    int index = 0;
    dlist::node* temp = new dlist::node;
    temp = a.head();
    dlist::node* temp1 = new dlist::node;
    temp1 = b.head();
    while (index < a.size()) {

        if (temp->value == temp1->value)
            index++;
        else {

            equal = false;
            break;

        }
        temp = temp->next;
        temp1 = temp1->next;

    }

    delete temp, temp1;
    return equal;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code defining `dlist`?

Comment: Hint: What happens with the two objects that you create? What are you actually deleting?

Comment: When you do `dlist::node* temp = new dlist::node` directly followed by `temp = a.head()`, it's the same as e.g. `int a = 10; a = 5;` and then wondering why `a` is not equal to `10`.

Comment: those `new` and `delete` statements are actually completely unnecessary in this code, the `new` is only creating a memory leak (since you redirect the pointers right after) and the `delete` are trying to free memory they did not allocate

Comment: `delete temp, temp1;` deallocates the memory pointed to by `temp` but not `temp1`. You need to use `delete temp; delete temp1;`.

Comment: @A.Godnov those functions are not part of the C++ standard (and I don't see what they have to do with the problem OP is experiencing)

Answer (score 2):

In this part of your code

```
dlist::node* temp = new dlist::node;
temp = a.head();
dlist::node* temp1 = new dlist::node;
temp1 = b.head();
```

you create and immediatly leak two objects.
Both lines with `new` are unneeded.
If you delete them, you do not leak anymore and you have same functionality otherwise.

Then it becomes clear, that this attempt to delete the temps

```
delete temp, temp1;
```

is unneeded, because they both are local pointers, but not pointing to anything locally instantiated. They are just pointing to not-to-be-deleted elements in your lists. (And I believe that this way of deleting two pointers cannot work, considering the way the comma operator works.)

Comment: So you mean memory Invasion?

Comment: @A.Godnov Sorry, I don't get your point. What do you mean by "memory Invasion"? My search engine has a lot of Startrek reference for that, but somehow I believe that is not what you refer to.

Answer (score 0):

`new` and `delete` are useless in there.
When you declare `dlist::node* temp` you are declaring a variable that can hold a address location.

You can either assign it the address of an existing area in the memory or allocate a new block of memory.

In the second case, you have to remember to delete the allocated block after use.

In your function, your are allocating memory, assigning the address of this memory to a variable (`dlist::node* temp`) and right after you make temp pointing on another address (`temp = a.head()`) which leads to a memory leak (the allocated memory is not addressed anymore by any variable).

You are making the same error with `temp1` variable.

Here is what your code should look like :

```
bool operator== (const dlist& a, const dlist& b)
{
    if (a.size() != b.size())
        return false;

    bool equal = true;
    int index = 0;
    dlist::node* temp = temp = a.head();
    dlist::node* temp1 = temp1 = b.head();
    while (index < a.size()) {

        if (temp->value == temp1->value)
            index++;
        else {

            equal = false;
            break;

        }
        temp = temp->next;
        temp1 = temp1->next;

    }

    return equal;
}
```

Comment: you do not need equal - just `return false`  instead of `equal = false` and `return true;` instead of `return equal;`

Comment: @Artemy, yes you're right, even though some people prefer to have only one return statement in their function (which is another debate). But my answer was only about the access violation issue.